# Periods to Date Calculation MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, powerbi

I am having an issue with the total on an MDX calculation.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[YTD InternetSalesAmount]
  AS Aggregate
   (
  PeriodsToDate
      (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
     )
    ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ), 
    FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
   VISIBLE = 1 ,  
    DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Internet Sales'  ;
```

The total as you can see below includes the July 2008 Sales Amount.

[image]

Below I have removed the July 2008 Sales Amount, But the Total is still showing the amount that includes July 2008 Sales Amount. It seems like the Calculated measures Total is not adjusting as the Rows are filtered out.

[image]

Any suggestions to get the Total adjust to the filtering.

Comment: what is the query that is being used to move the data into powerbi?

Comment: Uses live connection to SSAS.